# What happens when you hook both jumper cables to the positive on the battery?

Tags: engine

The other day I haphazardly hooked both jumper cables to the positive terminal of the battery.  Now the truck will not start,  there are no lights.  What happened?

Comment: depend on what the other end was hooked to..

Comment: It was a portable charger that was plugged into an outlet on the outside of the house.  THe charger started smoking.  That is when nothing on the truck worked.

Comment: nothing at all should have happened to the truck, you simply shorted (and probably ruined) the charger.  Obviously the truck battery was bad to begin with if you were trying to jump it.

Comment: It was a carcraft with 730 cold cranking amps that I got last year.    I have recently bought a new battery with 800 cold cranking amps to see if that would work on starting the truck.  No luck with that.

Comment: Also the reason I went to jump the truck was it would only make one click.  after the screw up with the charger it makes no noise, no lights, nothing at all.

Comment: have a check through your main fuses, maybe popped one of them

Comment: This is a serious question, exactly how did you attach both jumper cables to the positive terminal?  (I suspect you did something else that described)

Comment: the positive battery cable has two other wires coming to it as it my plow truck.  The two other wires had black protective coverings.  That is how I got screwed up.

Comment: Whatever happened to you vehicle

Answer (score 3):

Like agentp said you shorted out (and probably ruined) the charger. Nothing much should have happened to your battery except for the fact that it appears to be completely empty, just like it almost was before you tried to charge it.